# Async-Await & Bottleneck Rate Limiting using Promise.all

Tags: node.js, promise, async-await, intercom

I'm using an API which has a rate limit of 500 requests / min.
Therefore I decided to use [bottleneck](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bottleneck). But I need to execute array of async functions which generates a Promise to make that API call. I'm not sure I'm on the right way. Because API responses me with "Exceeded rate limit of 83 in 10_seconds" where I just only send 70 requests in 10 seconds.

Here is how I call the main function:

```
const result = await Helper.updateUsers(request.query.where);
..
..
```

Here is the helper.js

```
const Boom = require("boom");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Bottleneck = require("bottleneck");

const Intercom = require("intercom-client");

const config = require("../../config/config");

const client = new Intercom.Client({
  token: config.intercom.access_token
});

const User = mongoose.model("User");
const Shop = mongoose.model("Shop");

// create a rate limiter that allows up to 70 API calls per 10 seconds,
// with max concurrency of 70
const limiter = new Bottleneck({
  maxConcurrent: 70,
  minTime: 10000
});

// Helpers

// This function prepares a valid Intercom User Object.
// user -> User Object
// returns <Promise>
const prepareAndUpdateUser = async user => {
  try {
    let userData = {
      email: user.email,
      user_id: user._id,
      companies: []
    };
    Shop.find({ _id: { $in: user.account.shops } })
      .exec((err, shops) => {
        if (err) console.log("INTERCOM UPDATE USER", err);
        shops.forEach(shop => {
          let shopData = {
            company_id: shop._id,
            name: shop.name[shop.defaultLanguage.code]
          };
          userData.companies.push(shopData);
        });
        // Update Intercom Promise
        return client.users.create(userData);
      });
  } catch (e) {
    return Boom.boomify(err);
  }
};

module.exports.updateUsers = async query => {
  try {
    const users = await User.find(query)
      .populate("account")
      .limit(700);
    if (users && users.length > 0) {
      limiter.schedule(() => {
        const allTasks = users.map(
          async user => await prepareAndUpdateUser(user)
        );
        return Promise.all(allTasks);
      });
      return users.length;
    } else {
      return 0;
    }
  } catch (err) {
    return Boom.boomify(err);
  }
};
```

Am I using Bottleneck & Async-Await correct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first thing to point out is your use of callbacks in an `async` method instead of `await`ing a promise. You should use the promise returning version of `Shops.find()` and `await` the results.

```
async function prepareAndUpdateUser(user) {
    try {
        const shops = await Shop.find({ _id: { $in: user.account.shops } }).exec();
        return client.users.create({
            email: user.email,
            user_id: user._id,
            companies: shops.map(shop => {
                return {
                    company_id: shop._id,
                    name: shop.name[shop.defaultLanguage.code]
                };
            })
        });
    } catch (e) {
        return Boom.boomify(err);
    }
}
```

In your `updateUsers` method you're using the rate limiter backwards. You want to map the users into the rate limiter so that it can control when `prepareAndUpdateUser` is called, currently you'll be requesting everything in parallel. You also want to wait for promise returned by the rate limiter to resolve. Essentially you'll want to move `limiter.scehdule(...)` into `user.map(...)`.

```
async function updateUsers(query) {
    try {
        const users = await User.find(query)
            .populate("account")
            .limit(700);
        if (users && users.length > 0) {
            // Schedule an update for each user
            const allTasks = users.map(user => {
                // Schedule returns a promise that resolves when the operation is complete
                return limiter.schedule(() => {
                    // This method is called when the scheduler is ready for it
                    return prepareAndUpdateUser(user)
                })
            });
            // Wait for all the scheduled tasks to complete
            await Promise.all(allTasks);
            return users.length;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    } catch (err) {
        return Boom.boomify(err);
    }
}
```

Comment: I understand everything you said so well. I wouldn't find a better explanation. Thank you for your help!

Comment: OMG, couldn't thank you more! your answer was clear and precise. thank you!!